# Rearranging asymptotic notation

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

If $a \le b^{\frac{1+\log_{2}b}{2}}(1+o(1))$, then what is $b$ in terms of $a$? Whenever I try to rearrange this, I get in a huge mess...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: With relation to what is the $o(1)$ taken? $m$, around $\infty$? What asymptotics are you considering here?

Comment: sorry about the typo. m was meant to be b. does the question make sense now?

Comment: Does $b$ go to infinity, or $0$?

Comment: it's related to graph theory, so infinity

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see (and if I didn't make any mistake), it should be something like \begin{align*}
b\geq 2^{\displaystyle\sqrt{2\log_2 a }-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt{2\log_2a}} + o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2a}}\right)}.
\end{align*}
Plugging in back the expression, you get
$$
a \leq a\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{256\log_2 a}}\cdot\left(1+o(1)\right) = a \left(1+o(1)\right)
$$
when $a\to\infty$.

Comment: would you mind explaining how you managed this?

Comment: By successive refinements: writing the RHS of the inequality as $2^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\log^2 b + \log b\right)}$, ignoring the $1+o(1)$ factor for a first approximation; then, seeing for which expression it matched the lower bound of $a$: first only considering the first term in the exponent and solving $a=2^{\frac{1}{2}\log^2 b}$, plugging in back to see what was missing and then adding a term, then another one, etc. until it became sufficiently accurate (matching the the precision of the $1+o(1)$)
(all logarithms are in base $2$ here)